# Issues getting recursive regex to work, getting loop error

Tags: php, regex

My actual match line at the moment is

```
preg_match_all('/(\{%IF:(.+?)%\}\r?\n?)(.+?)(\{%ENDIF:\2%\}\r?\n?)/s',$this->tpl_raw,$if_controls,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

That looks for

```
{%IF:NAME%}Do 1{%ENDIF:NAME%}
```

and I get that match.  The problem is, what it's not doing, and I want to is in cases like this

```
{%IF:NAME%}Do 1{%IF:OTHERNAME%} Do 2{%ENDIF:OTHERNAME%}{%ENDIF:NAME%}
```

I cannot get it to ALSO match that inner portion.

Based on the original answer here, I looked into doing this

```
preg_match_all('/(\{%IF:(.+?)%\}\r?\n?)(.+?)|(?R)(\{%ENDIF:\2%\})\r?\n?/s',$this->tpl_working,$if_controls,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

But that gives me

```
preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: recursive call could loop indefinitely at offset 31
```

Can anyone assist with how I can make this work?

Comment: Nested tags should better be parsed using code rather than from regex

Comment: You know, actually the _NAME_ or _OTHERNAME_ is irrelavent other than an identifier. The actual nesting is controlled by the `IF .. IF .. ENDIF .. ENDIF`

Comment: Try this `'/(?is)(?:(?>{%IF:\w*%})((?&core)|){%ENDIF:\w*%})(?(DEFINE)(?<core>(?>(?&content)|(?>{%IF:\w*%})(?:(?&core)|){%ENDIF:\w*%})+)(?<content>(?>(?!{%(?:IF:|ENDIF:)\w*%}).)+))/'`